# How to keep table and equations to the left side?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
First find how many days between July 22 and Nov 4
    \[\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
    \hline 
    Month &       & days \\
    \hline \hline
    July  &  31-22  & 9 \\
    August &       & 31 \\
    September &       & 30 \\
    October &&31\\
    November&&4\\
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{total } & 105 days \\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}\]

\begin{flalign*} 
PV &= \frac{FV}{1+r \times t} \\\\
 &= \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.07 \times \frac{105}{365}\right)} \\\\
 &= \dfrac{2000}{1.020137}\\\\
 &= \$980.26
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

I would like to keep everything to the left, but currently the table is centred.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have defined a table inside a display equation(!), you may use `fleqn` as the option for the `documentclass`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt} %% reduce the indent for equations to 0pt.
\begin{document}
First find how many days between July 22 and Nov 4
    \[\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
    \hline
    Month &       & days \\
    \hline \hline
    July  &  31-22  & 9 \\
    August &       & 31 \\
    September &       & 30 \\
    October &&31\\
    November&&4\\
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{total } & 105 days \\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}\]

    \begin{flalign*}
PV &= \frac{FV}{1+r \times t} \\\\
 &= \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.07 \times \frac{105}{365}\right)} \\\\
 &= \dfrac{2000}{1.020137}\\\\
 &= \$980.26
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Now it is time to do things in right way. `tabular` need not be used inside `\[...\]`. And as noted by Gonzalo, instead of using double `\\` to leave some extra vertical space between equations, one can use the optional argument like`\\[<len>]`, where `<len>` can be `\jot` or any unit of length like `pt` or `cm` or multiples of `baselineskip` as in this example, where nothing is changed in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\begin{document}

First find how many days between July 22 and Nov 4
\par\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
    \hline
    Month &       & days \\
    \hline \hline
    July  &  31-22  & 9 \\
    August &       & 31 \\
    September &       & 30 \\
    October &&31\\
    November&&4\\
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{total } & 105 days \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
here
\begin{flalign*}
    PV  &= \frac{FV}{1+r \times t} && \\[\jot]
        &= \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.07 \times \dfrac{105}{365}\right)} && \\[.5cm]
        &= \dfrac{2000}{1.020137} && \\[\baselineskip] 
        &= \$980.26 &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `\[...\]` for the table. A simple `\par\noindent` before `\begin{tabular}` will do. Also, instead of using `\\\\ ` to increase the spacing, you could suggest changing `\jot`.

Comment: Harish Is is possible that nothing outside {document} environment is modified? the preamble must be left as it is, otherwise all my other notes will be modified too.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I missed totally, Sorry. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user21494: See the update above where nothing is changed in the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want left alignment (which doesn't seem too good), then you can do like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
First find how many days between July 22 and Nov 4
\begin{flalign*}\settowidth{\dimen0}{$PV$}
  \makebox[\dimen0][l]{\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
    \hline
    Month &   & days \\
    \hline \hline
    July  &  31-22  & 9 \\
    August &       & 31 \\
    September &       & 30 \\
    October &&31\\
    November&&4\\
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{total } & 105 days \\
    \hline
 \end{tabular}}&&&\\[\jot]
PV &= \frac{FV}{1+r \times t} &&\\[\jot]
 &= \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.07 \times \frac{105}{365}\right)} &&\\[\jot]
 &= \frac{2000}{1.020137}&&\\[\jot]
 &= \$980.26&&\vphantom{\frac{\mathstrut}{\mathstrut}}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

The `tabular` is set to have an apparent width equal to "PV". Instead of "empty lines" it's better to give a small amount of space (`\jot`, which can also be `2\jots` or `1.5\jots` or whatever, take your pick). In order to get left alignment you have to add another "fake" column, represented by the final `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

You have used table inside display equation. If you remove that then table will automatically come to left side. and for equation you can use && at the end of the line to bring it to left. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}  

First find how many days between July 22 and Nov 4\\\\  
   \begin{tabular}{|lll|}  
    \hline   
    Month &       & days \\   
    \hline \hline  
    July  &  31-22  & 9 \\  
    August &       & 31 \\  
    September &       & 30 \\  
    October &&31\\  
    November&&4\\  
    \hline \hline  
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{total } & 105 days \\  
    \hline  
   \end{tabular}  
    \begin{flalign*}   
PV &= \frac{FV}{1+r \times t} && \\\\  
 &= \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.07 \times \frac{105}{365}\right)} && \\\\  
 &= \dfrac{2000}{1.020137} && \\\\  
 &= \$980.26 &&  
\end{flalign*}  
\end{document}
```

Hope this will help.